# can't activate activesupport (>= 2.3.2, runtime), already activated activesupport-2.1.2. what does it mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

while trying to start some old revision of an opensource rails project confronted with a cloudy error message:

"can't activate activesupport (>= 2.3.2, runtime), already activated activesupport-2.1.2"

What does it mean? Either versions of rails and activesupport are installed on my box.

I'm confused...

Answer (score 4):

Generally, a gem or plugin is loading 2.1.2 before Rails attempts to load 2.3.2. Best way to figure it out might be to comment out each gem requirement in environment.rb one at a time and see what happens.

Comment: Had the same problem, only with different version numbers. In my case, I had to downgrade my version of the activemerchant gem.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need the older version of the gem the easiest way to get up and running is to remove it.

```
gem uninstall activesupport
```

To remove the old versions.

Comment: Worked like a charm in my case, after an upgrade to Fedora 26. I also had to `dnf install compat-readline6` to get `libreadline.so.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed the recent active support gem?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the trace associated with the error message.  I recently encountered this problem where there was an instance of script/process/reaper which was getting run by Capistrano and preloading the older version.  In the trace it showed the file which was trying to load the older version.

Answer (score 0):

with that error, Rails' Active Support is not working, because on your machine the Active Support Gem is installed with 2.1.2 version while the project requires a recent version (2.3.2) of that gem.

IMHO, I think you have to upgrade the gem, because a lot a times I solved typing this on terminal:

gem install gem_name

where gem_name is the name of the gem you want to install. Ruby will remove the old version and install the newer. 
Download the activesupport-2.3.2.gem from http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=570
and place it on the directory of your project and execute the command.

You can find here other gems on: http://rubygems.org/

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error but later i updated the Rails and downloaded all the dependencies and issue got resolved.