# Unable to init the pod in Xcode Project

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, macos, cocoapods

Can anybody help me to solve this issue?

I got this error when i want to init pods in my xcode project:

```
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:242:in `activate': can't activate activesupport (>= 4.0.2, < 5, runtime) for ["cocoapods-1.5.3"], 

already activated activesupport-5.2.2 for ["cocoapods-core-1.5.3", "cocoapods-1.5.3"] (Gem::LoadError)

    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:258:in `block in activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:257:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:257:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:1146:in `gem'
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199421/cant-activate-activesupport-2-3-2-runtime-already-activated-activesuppor

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall the gem activesupport. this may help

```
gem uninstall activesupport
```